# How to make sure that %PATH% disappears if PATH is undefined?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I tried to do the following

```
set PATH=
echo foo%PATH%bar
```

and I get

```
foo%PATH%bar
```

if I add a space after the = sign in the set, I get

```
foo bar
```

I also tried

```
set PATH=""
```

and I get

```
foo""bar
```

What I want is

```
foobar
```

Similar questions around the web didn't solve the issue. Apparently, if undefined, the behavior should be as I expect, but this is not the case.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer as it probably doesn't solve your problem, but I just found that this works as expected inside of a batch file. It's only when running it manually from the command line that your problem seems to surface.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I check if a variable is not defined?

> I tried to do the following:
>
> ```
> set PATH=
> echo foo%PATH%bar
> ```
>
> and I get:
>
> ```
> foo%PATH%bar
> ```

You can use `if not defined` to produce the result you want.

Use the following command in a `cmd` shell:

```
if not defined PATH (echo foobar) else echo foo%path%bar
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>set PATH=

F:\test>if not defined PATH (echo foobar) else echo foo%path%bar
foobar

F:\test>
```

and if PATH is defined:

```
F:\test>if not defined PATH (echo foobar) else echo foo%path%bar
fooC:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\Calibre\;;C:\apps\NTP\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\bar

F:\test>

---
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.